# Multiplicar cada elemento (de una fila) de una matriz por otro numero (cualquiera) y luego sumarlos

Tags: c#

Estoy practicando c# e intento sacar la siguiente formula. (la del cuadro rojo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un método que me genera un array aleatorio; encontré la forma de sumar todos los elementos de la fila, pero quiero que primero cada elemento se multiplique por la variable de tipo double = "div" y luego se sumen, justo como se ve en la formula de la imagen anterior.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    public void Formula(int[,] arr ,int c, int f)
    {
        double div = ((double)1 / (double)f);
        Console.WriteLine("Division: " + div);

        //SUMA DE LINEAS
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++) //filas
        {
            int suma = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                suma += arr[i, j];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Linea " + i + " = " + suma);
        }



    }
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de solamente aumentar el número a la suma:

```
suma += arr[i, j];
```

Puedes adicionarle el valor multiplicado por la variable `div`:

```
suma += arr[i, j] * div;
```

Eso sí, deberás declarar suma como `double` para admitir decimales, o redondear después si necesitas un entero.

Comment: Gracias amigo. Me ayudaste mucho! :D